# chrome extension: how to bind/hook to the browser's "search invoked" event?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension, and I want to want to extend (but not override) the browser's search (ctrl-F or cmd-F) feature.

Is there any way to make my extension receive a message when the browser's search feature gets invoked, along with the search term entered.

(Is the search box UI in HTML? If so, is there a way to access it, so that I could bind to the keypress/keydown event on it search input element?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Till date there is no way you can *access Standard Chrome Find Dialog* or *receive a message when the browser's search feature gets invoked* or *rendering search box UI in HTML?*

( Which is triggered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>).

However, you can use [window.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.find)<sup>1</sup>.

## Work Around

This Work Around will **Override** because **extension is not possible till date**.

Define your own Command using [chrome.commands](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html) API

```
"commands":{
    "sample":{
        "suggested_key" : {
            "default":"Ctrl+F",
            "windows":"Ctrl+F"
        },
        "description":"Thisismycustomkeyforchromeextension"
    },
}
```

and add a listener for your command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {

    //Do what ever you want here
})
```

This will override Standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and use your own [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) to frame all the UI and functional Logic for scraping the Page for related Content.

1: `window.find()` scope falls in selected text only

## References

- [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)
- [Commands API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html)

Comment: Accepted this answer since as you mentioned, there seems to be no way to hook into Chrome's ctrl+f event.